# What do white notes mean in cubase key editor?

Tags: cubase

In my key editor in Cubase, some MIDI notes are drawn white. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that these notes appear to be muted for some reason. [Here](http://www.cubase.net/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?t=54690&sid=d04d8dbfcc84168b5f0a433662e24324) is an an explanation of how to "unmute" these.